# Elasticsearch npm: Passing AWS Credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, elasticsearch

So I am trying to use the Elasticsearch npm client, but I am having issues with authentication. I am currently using authentication based on an IAM user's identity. For obvious reasons I don't want to move to open security and I would also rather use IAM user's identity over IP-based authentication.

IAM gives a user a username and password that are used as credentials upon the request. I'm not really sure how to pass them and my Elasticsearch server keeps timing out. Here is what I have tried so far. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/auth-reference.html) says to pass it as the `auth` key in a Client config object. I can confirm that the username and password and correct, and that the endpoint is the one provided by AWS.

**aws.js**

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const envs = require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = function () {
    return new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: [{
            apiVersion: '2.3',
            protocol: 'https',
            auth: `${envs.username}:${envs.password}`,
            host:`${envs.endpoint}`
        }]
    })
}
```

**index.js**

```
const client = require('./aws')();

client.ping({
    // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
    requestTimeout: Infinity
}, function(error) {
    console.log('pass')
    if (error) {
        console.trace(error);
    } else {
        console.log('All is well');
    }
});
```

Any questions or comment would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out. For future reference, elasticsearch JS does not have a method for signing for AWS. It only supports [SSL signed and basic authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/auth-reference.html). Therefore you can use [this NPM](https://github.com/TheDeveloper/http-aws-es) called `http-aws-es`. It uses the AWS SDK to sign for Elasticsearch using your IAM access key id and secret access key. Here is what I ended up with for my Elasticsearch client

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const AWSConnector = require('http-aws-es'),
const envs = require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = function () {
    return new elasticsearch.Client({
        connectionClass: AWSConnector,
        apiVersion: '2.3',
        port: 443,
        protocol: 'https',
        host:`${envs.endpoint}`,
        amazonES: {
            region: 'us-east-1',
            accessKey: envs.accessKeyId,
            secretKey: envs.secretAccessKey
        }
    })
}
```

One other thing to note is that I had to set the port to `443`. It would be port `80` if the protocol were http. The Elasticsearch JS library defaults to port `9200` for obvious reasons. If you don't specify the port, it will always default to `9200` regardless of the host you add.

Comment: I wish I could give you all the upvotes, I'd been fighting this for ages. Why the actual heck does AWS not provide this functionality as part of aws-sdk?!!

Comment: Any update on this for 2019? Doesn't seem to work with the latest versions of these libs, even if I ignore the TypeScript errors.

Comment: If you're coming across this trying to use the `@elastic/elasticsearch` package, checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/@acuris/aws-es-connection

Answer (score 1):

this is the code that worked for me.

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var options = {
    host: 'host',
    port:443,
    protocol:'https',
    connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'),
    awsConfig:new AWS.Config({
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials('aws_access_key', 'aws_secret_key'),
        region: 'us-east-1'
    })
};
var client = require('elasticsearch').Client(options);


client.ping({
  // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
  requestTimeout: 3000
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});
```